# Login as Customer problem

Tags: magento-1.8, login

[magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer-by-praxigento.html](http://magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer-by-praxigento.html) for login from the admin as customer but I have a problem when I log in to one customer and log out then go to another all products in cart from previous customer are copy in next customer cart the current one are deleted and products from previous customer are added any help or suggestion Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of the extension which should be fixed.

Theoratically the cart should be cleared after logging out. I think you don't log out or at least, the logout doesn't work as intended.

So the cart of the customer is still in the session and is merged (as intended) with the cart of the customer. Idea here is: The customer is logged in and shopping, then he logs out. He comes back, shopps again and now logs in, so the items from the first shopping experience is added to the cart.

Your problem here is, that the wrong carts are merged.

Just an idea. If the items are deleted as you write, then this might be wrong or the cart is just replaced instead of merged.

Check what happens in your session while you login/logout and what is merged, when you log in.

Comment: Yes But from that I can see i go directly to customer page and after that I use default logout function of magento and user is loged out the point is the when i clean cookies on the browser and go back to admin and log in with other customer data's in cart are not changed you are write but module only use login function and for logut it gets magento default function should't that clean the session

Comment: Should, but obviously it doesn't :-) So happy digging and debugging.

Answer (score 3):

To clear quote for logged in customers add this code

```
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuote(Mage::getModel('sales/quote'));
```

to Praxigento_LoginAs_LoginController class (line 54):

```
            ...
            /** establish new customer session */
            $validatorData = $session->getValidatorData();
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuote(Mage::getModel('sales/quote'));
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && ($operatorIp == $validatorData['remote_addr'])) {
            ...
```

Hope, it helps :)

Regards